# Make fat jar from the project with fat jar itself, using sbt assembly

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt-assembly to make my scala project into a fat jar.

This project is using ***play-json***, and ***AWS SDK***.

In the meantime, it is also using ***DynamoDB Transaction Lib*** as a fat jar, which is using ***Jackson*** and ***AWS SDK*** of another version.

When I used sbt assembly to make jar, error came out because of same path of libs between jackson, joda-date and other dependence shared by the AWS SDKs that I used and the ones used by DynamoDB Transaction Lib.

Due to DynamoDB Transaction Lib its own issue, I must use these two versions of both jackson and AWS SDK.

Is there any way to solve it by using merge strategy?

THX in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fat jar is for deployment only. Using it as a library is a really bad idea.

> Due to DynamoDB Transaction Lib its own issue, I must use these two versions of both jackson and AWS SDK.

Are you saying you need to use two different versions of jackson simultaneously? I don't think sbt-assembly can help you with that. Merge strategy can pick one of them.

Comment: You are right, use a fat jar as a library is a bad idea. I finally figured out a way to use the version of AWS and Jackson that DynamoDB Transaction Library uses. It was a big work however. Anyway, thank you!